# Remove the value after the third dot(.)using PHP

Tags: php

Remove the value of the string after the third dot(.) using PHP. I want to remove the value but for now I just counting the it using switch case. But in some cases it won't work if I concat a number after it.

```
<?php

$dnsserver='192.168.5.3';
$dnsserver_length =strlen($dnsserver); 
switch ($dnsserver_length) {
        case 8:
            $a=substr($dnsserver, 0, -1); 
            for ($i=1; $i < 256; $i++) { 
                $data1 = array(
                'kf_ipaddress_ipaddress' => $a.''.$i,
                'kf_ipaddress_status' => $kf_ipaddress_status,
                );
                $this->Kf_defaultgateway_model->insert_ipaddress($data1);
            }
        case 9:
            $b=substr($dnsserver, 0, -1); 
            for ($i=1; $i < 256; $i++) { 
                $data1 = array(
                'kf_ipaddress_ipaddress' => $b.''.$i,
                'kf_ipaddress_status' => $kf_ipaddress_status,
                );
                $this->Kf_defaultgateway_model->insert_ipaddress($data1);
            }
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: What works and what doesn't work?

Comment: I am trying to create an 255 IP address base by just removing the value after the third dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer by following the example at http://codepad.org/AzlNhZq6

```
<?php
$dnsserver='192.168.5.3';
echo strtok($dnsserver, '.') . '.' . strtok('.').'.' . strtok('.'). '.';
?>
```

Comment: great. Depends on what you choose as per your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your try with the string length works (as you expect) only in very specific cases, when the IP address first two sections are 3 digit long, the third section is one digit long, etc. It's not really flexible.

Start learning regular expressions.

For any kind of string (based on your question's title):

```
$s = preg_replace("/^(([^\.]+\.){3}).*$/", "$1", $dnsserver);
```

Or specificly for IP addresses:

```
$s = preg_replace("/^(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}).*$/", "$1", $dnsserver);

// These both will do like:
// 192.168.1.100 -> 192.168.1.
// 1.1.1.100     -> 1.1.1.
// 1.12.123.100  -> 1.12.123.
// etc.
```

See more at https://www.regular-expressions.info  or other similar sites.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion as per your question title.

You can use this code :

```
$dnsserver ='192.168.5.3';
$temp = explode('.', $dnsserver);
unset($temp[count($temp ) - 1]);
echo implode('.', $temp);
```

[demo snippet](http://codepad.org/5JOGwgxG)

Comment: What if string is `192.168.5`? Do you know `array_pop`?

Comment: I suppose if it is a IP address then it should have four sections. and yes there are many ways to solve one problem.

Comment: Thanks @TouheedKhan for the answer but I got an answer above.

Comment: congrats, happy to help :)